# Spinner functionality issues in Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: android

My users are reporting an issue in Android 6.0 related to Spinner Control. Users are unable to select any item in the list. The same application is working fine with < Android 6+ versions. Here is the

[Screenshot of issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsImF.jpg)

Here is my sample code :

**XML Code**

```
<Spinner
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/spinnerImportance"
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
android:popupBackground="#f5f5f5"
android:prompt="@string/spinner_prompt"
android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
android:dropDownWidth="fill_parent" />
```

**Java Code**

```
public class EvaluationActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private Spinner spinnerImportance;
String[] importance = {"Select", "1 or less - Low importance", "2 - Moderate importance", "3 - High importance", "4 - Exceptionally important"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_evaluation);

        //Importance
        spinnerImportance = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerImportance);
        spinnerImportance.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterImportance = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, importance);
        dataAdapterImportance.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);            

        spinnerImportance.setAdapter(dataAdapterImportance);
        spinnerImportance.setSelection(getIndexFromScore(abs.M1, IMPORTANCE));
}

//Rest of the Code
}
```

I don't have Android 6 powered device to fix and test the same. Any sure shot solution will be of great help.

Comment: _don't have Android 6 powered device_ ??? Use emulator :)

Comment: @SripadRaj I am used to test with actual devices. Emulators are damn slow. Anyways I don't mind using emulators for this particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same issue and in my case it was a styling issue.

I was displaying an `AppCompatSpinner` with a style I had created specifically for dialog type spinners so it had an attribute defined for `spinnerMode` set to `dialog`.  My base spinner style inherits from `Widget.AppCompat.Spinner` which by default has the `clickable` attribute set to `true` because spinners are of type `dropdown` by default. This was causing the entire spinner to register the click rather than the individual items.

So adding a `clickable` attribute set to `false` in my dialog specific spinner style fixed the issue for me.

The fact that this adjustment is not necessary on <6.0 devices is still odd.