# Spinner Items Not Clickable

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner that i fill with 4 elements. During startup onItemSelected method gets executed correctly and the toast message is displayed. However when i open the spinner and try to click any item, no event is called and the spinner popup will not close unless i press the spinner arrow. In other words I can not interact with spinner items.

Below is the activity code for the spinner

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:popupBackground="@color/red"
        android:clickable="true"
        style="@style/spinner250"/>
```

Below is the style for the spinner

```
    <style name="spinner250">
    <item name="android:layout_width"> 250dp </item>
    <item name="android:layout_height"> match_parent </item>
    <item name="android:textColor"> @color/blue </item>
    <item name="android:textSize"> 12sp </item>
    </style>
```

And this is my java code for interacting with the spinner
    package com.example.android.gjobat;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import static android.R.attr.country;
import static android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createFromResource;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     OnItemSelectedListener {

public Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String[] items = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"};

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        // User selected item
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item + " selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After spending entirely one day with this i figured out that the problem was caused by

```
 <item name="android:inputType">textCapCharacters</item>
```

that was in my styles.xml file. I have no idea why this line of code caused the error but at least it works now after i removed that line. Below a full copy of my styles.xml file prior to removing the faulty line

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:inputType">textCapCharacters</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I hope this helps someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

SOMETIMES THE ISSUE MAY ALSO BE BECAUSE YOU HAVE PLACED YOUR SPINNER OUTSIDE THE LAYOUT YOU ARE CALLING . THIS WILL NOT SHOW ANY ERROR BUT YOU WILL NOT BE ABLE TO INTERACT WITH THE SPINNER VIEW

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please do not use CAPS, it makes things more difficult to read than they should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onItemClickListener like below

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item number: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the xml attribute `android:clickable="true"` from the `Spinner` widget. It could be that the entire spinner is registering the click event rather than the individual spinner items.

Possible duplicate of [Spinner functionality issues in Android 6.0 Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726948/spinner-functionality-issues-in-android-6-0-marshmallow/39985418)