# Simple Spinner Items Not Clickable

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner that i fill with 4 elements. During startup onItemSelected method gets executed correctly and the toast message is displayed. However when i open the spinner and try to click any item, no event is called and the spinner popup will not close unless i press the spinner arrow. In other words I can not interact with spinner items.

**Below is the activity code for the spinner**

```
<Spinner
           android:id="@+id/sp_size"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**this is my java code**

```
 ArrayList<String> strItemsize = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("H 1", " H 2", " H 3", "H 4", "H 5"));
        final ArrayList<Integer> Hsize = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(18, 16, 14, 12, 10));

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSize = new ArrayAdapter<String>(App.CurentActivity,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, strItemsize);
        adapterSize.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spSize.setAdapter(adapterSize);
        spSize.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                App.ShowMessage().ShowToast(""+i, ToastEnum.TOAST_SHORT_TIME);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

i searching but dose not  solve it.this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007222/spinner-items-not-clickable) is my problem like but dos not my solotion.

Answer (score 0):

Set in XML for spinner clickable=true
Or use Widget.AppCompat.Spinner instead. Seems to be Marshmallow bug

Comment: Change in gradle the target SDK and compile SDK to the latest. Also the appcompat to be in sync.

Comment: write my spinner xml code like this:     <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
           android:id="@+id/sp_size"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> but not work

Comment: Why change target sdk?in another project with this target worked.my target sdk is: 
 targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: No one guides me؟

Answer (score 0):

You should set spinner attribute android:clickable=true in your XML.

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/sp_size"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable=true />
```